# Typo3 tt_news bug in latest view

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

I've a problem with `tt_news` extension "latest view".I am using `tt_news` version 3.4.0 and typo3 version 4.7.14.

In the plugin `tt_news`, set to show "Latest News", but it refuses to show anything.

I did a thorough comparision with configurations and I checked pageTS and other TS. I've almost 130 news items in the list. 
Its displayed correctly in list view and single view. But in latest view its displayed as "no news items".

When I put 5 or 6 news items, its displayed correctly.

I guess this is an Overflow bug of the `tt_news` plugin. Is anybody know regarding this?

Comment: Is there an error in your PHP log? What does `it refuses to show anything` mean in particular? Is the whole page empty or just the content element? Is the wrapping HTML of the plugin present or is that also missing?

Comment: In error log, it does not show anything. Other content elements are rendered properly in that page. In the latest mode, its displayed "no news items in the list". I am totally confusing. Is there any overflow bug in latest mode?

Comment: No, probably not. I guess the storagePID or another setting is wrong. Check them in the TS object browser, I'm pretty sure you just have set the wrong uid where the records are loaded from.

Comment: Ok..Once again I'll check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.

In latest view we don't need to give archive date for news items. If archive date is given no news items displayed in latest view.

We can use "plugin.tt_news.displayArchivedInLatest = 1" typoscript to display an archived news items in latest view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the template if there are typos in the markers. Compare your template with the orginal from `EXT:tt_news/res/tt_news_v3_template.html`. I don't think that its a tt_news bug because I never had any problems and use it in about 20 projects.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. But the issue is not related to that. Because I've 3 domains in the same typo3 backend. All these 3 uses same template file. But in other two domains, its displayed correctly. I only saw the difference in number of news items. This domain have 130 news and other two have only 5 or 6.